# String not returned

Tags: java, android, string

I have create function to return string, that string is appending lot of other string from model class. Please see my code below

```
public static String getDefaultParameters(Context context){
        System.out.println("Default Params");

        PreDefinedAttributes preDefinedAttributes = new PreDefinedAttributes(context);


        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("&_vpw="+preDefinedAttributes.getWidth());
        sb.append("&_vph="+preDefinedAttributes.getHeight());
        sb.append("&sdk_version="+preDefinedAttributes.getSdk_version());
        sb.append("&_src=android-sdk"
                +"&_os="+preDefinedAttributes.getMobile_os());
        sb.append("&os_version="+preDefinedAttributes.getMobile_version());
        sb.append("&manufacturer="+preDefinedAttributes.getMobile_manufacturer());

        System.out.println("Builder Params "+sb.toString());

        return  sb.toString();
    }
```

But am not getting Builder Params value in the log. I have used StringBuilder and normal String with + sign as well, nothing works.

Code ForPredefined Attributes Class, where i have populate the param data and returns the values.

```
public class PreDefinedAttributes {
private Context mContext;
private String mobile_os,mobile_model,mobile_brand,mobile_version,mobile_manufacturer;
private String sdk_version,src,appname,appversion;
private String lat="",lng="",device_id;
private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION=0;
private int height,width;


public PreDefinedAttributes(Context context) {
mContext = context;

    this.mobile_model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    this.mobile_os = "Android";
    this.mobile_brand = Build.BRAND + " "+Build.PRODUCT;
    this.mobile_version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    this.mobile_manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;

    this.sdk_version = Utils.SDK_VERSION;
    this.src = Utils.SDK_SRC;
    this.device_id = Utils.getDeviceId(mContext);
    try {
        this.appversion = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    }catch (Exception e){
        this.appversion = "";
    }

    final PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }
    this.appname = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");





     height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
     width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;



    //loadPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    try {
        SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(mContext,
                new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNewLocationAvailable(SingleShotLocationProvider.GPSCoordinates location) {
                        Log.d("Location", "my location is " + location.toString());
                        lat = ""+location.latitude;
                        lng = ""+location.longitude;
                    }
                });
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {

    }


}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public String getDevice_id() {
    return device_id;
}

public String getMobile_brand() {
    return mobile_brand;
}


public String getMobile_model() {
    return mobile_model;
}

public String getMobile_os() {
    return mobile_os;
}

public String getMobile_version() {
    return mobile_version;
}

public String getMobile_manufacturer() {
    return mobile_manufacturer;
}

public String getSdk_version() {
    return sdk_version;
}

public String getSrc() {
    return src;
}

public String getAppname() {
    return appname;
}

public String getAppversion() {
    return appversion;
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public String getLng() {
    return lng;
}
```

}

Comment: you are returning String result which contains nothing replace your statement with return result to return sb.toString()

Comment: @Waleed Asim System.out.println("Builder Params "+sb.toString()); this line not print

Comment: why getting downvote my question. Am not getting solution which i have tried.

Comment: this is adapter class or fragment or activity?

Comment: This is java class only used for project utility

Comment: @Sankari share code for `PreDefinedAttributes`

Comment: @Sankari put `try catch` in your code and check if any exception is occurring.

Comment: @Prem please check my updated code

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV i have tried no exception throws. weird error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your **`String result = "";`** is null check it Your are returning null string change it

You should

`return  sb.toString();`

instead of

`return  result;`

**EDIT**

```
public class PreDefinedAttributes {
    private Context mContext;
    private String mobile_os, mobile_model, mobile_brand, mobile_version, mobile_manufacturer;
    private String sdk_version, src, appname, appversion;
    private String lat = "", lng = "", device_id;
    private static final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
    private int height, width;


    public PreDefinedAttributes(Context context) {
        mContext = context;

        this.mobile_model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
        this.mobile_os = "Android";
        this.mobile_brand = Build.BRAND + " " + Build.PRODUCT;
        this.mobile_version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
        this.mobile_manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;

        this.sdk_version = 16 + "";
        this.src = 16 + "";
        this.device_id = 16 + "";
        try {
            this.appversion = mContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.appversion = "";
        }

        final PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
        ApplicationInfo ai;
        try {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            ai = null;
        }
        this.appname = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");


        height = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        width = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;


        //loadPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);


    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public String getDevice_id() {
        return device_id;
    }

    public String getMobile_brand() {
        return mobile_brand;
    }


    public String getMobile_model() {
        return mobile_model;
    }

    public String getMobile_os() {
        return mobile_os;
    }

    public String getMobile_version() {
        return mobile_version;
    }

    public String getMobile_manufacturer() {
        return mobile_manufacturer;
    }

    public String getSdk_version() {
        return sdk_version;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }

    public String getAppversion() {
        return appversion;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
}
```

**get values like this**

```
 PreDefinedAttributes preDefinedAttributes = new PreDefinedAttributes(this);


        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("&_vpw=" + preDefinedAttributes.getWidth());
        sb.append("&_vph=" + preDefinedAttributes.getHeight());
        sb.append("&sdk_version=" + preDefinedAttributes.getSdk_version());
        sb.append("&_src=android-sdk"
                + "&_os=" + preDefinedAttributes.getMobile_os());
        sb.append("&os_version=" + preDefinedAttributes.getMobile_version());
        sb.append("&manufacturer=" + preDefinedAttributes.getMobile_manufacturer());

        Log.e("Builder Params " , sb.toString());
```

**OUtput**

[image]

Comment: I did that too, not getting result

Comment: @Sankari print values in log i think you are not getting values from your **`PreDefinedAttributes`** class

Comment: @Sankari you code in working fine in y device i get the result **11-30 11:39:41.748 2888-2888/com.ncrypted.bistrostays E/Builder Params: &_vpw=1080&_vph=1794&sdk_version=16&_src=android-sdk&_os=Android&os_version=6.0&manufacturer=unknown**

Comment: thanks i remove lat long function now works fine

Comment: @Sankari happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your return statement like this

```
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: but even System.out.println("Builder Params "+sb.toString()); not prints the string